# Need help creating an Input Field & Scroll View [Unity3d-C#]

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I've been trying to create an input field which upon editing activate the scroll View below and display relevant information to the subject(ex:username,address...), but on calling the input field event to activate the scroll view it won't accept the function which I have created. Thank for reading my terrible English and help whoever you're.

```
public InputField username;
    public InputField password;
    public List<string> usernamelist;
    public Button enter;
    public ScrollRect usernamedataload;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        string temp = "";
        if (PlayerPrefs.GetString ("username") == null) {
            username.text = temp;
        } else if (PlayerPrefs.GetString ("password") == null) {
            password.text = temp;
        } else {
            username.text = PlayerPrefs.GetString ("username");
            password.text = PlayerPrefs.GetString ("password");
        }
        usernamedataload.gameObject.SetActive (false);

    }   

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        enter.onClick.AddListener (enterKeyDown);
        username.onValueChanged.AddListener(selectUsernameInput);
        username.onEndEdit.AddListener (endEditingUsernameInput);
    }
    void selectUsernameInput(){
        usernamedataload.gameObject.SetActive (true);
        usernamedataload.content.GetChild (usernamelist);
    }
    void endEditingUsernameInput(){
        usernamedataload.gameObject.SetActive (false);
    }
```

Comment: What exactly is not being activated, the void selectUsernameInput or the setactive inside the void?

Comment: well the ideas of the code is when the user type their username in the input field the scroll view which is disable right now will activate.But i call the selectUsernameInput or the endEditingUsernameInput it set "A method or delegate `IdAndPasswordController.endEditingUsernameInput()' parameters do not match delegate `UnityEngine.Events.UnityAction<string>(string)' parameters ".

Answer (score 1):

It's very hard to understand this question but I can spot big problems already. You are suppose to register to a UI event once. Right now, you are registering to three events *every frame* in the *Update()* function. Move those code to the *Start()* function.

> calling the input field event to activate the scroll view it won't
>   accept the function which I have created

Wrap delegate around the function you are passing in it. For example, `username.onValueChanged.AddListener(delegate { selectUsernameInput(); });`

[`Transform.GetChild`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.GetChild.html) takes `int` as parameter but you are passing `List` to it with `usernamedataload.content.GetChild(usernamelist);`. I can't tell why you are trying to do that but you should pass an `int` into it like (1,2,3,4).

You can get started with the code below. It fixes all the problems mentioned above and will compile.

```
public InputField username;
public InputField password;
public List<string> usernamelist;
public Button enter;
public ScrollRect usernamedataload;

// Use this for initialization
void Start()
{
    string temp = "";
    if (PlayerPrefs.GetString("username") == null)
    {
        username.text = temp;
    }
    else if (PlayerPrefs.GetString("password") == null)
    {
        password.text = temp;
    }
    else
    {
        username.text = PlayerPrefs.GetString("username");
        password.text = PlayerPrefs.GetString("password");
    }
    usernamedataload.gameObject.SetActive(false);

    enter.onClick.AddListener(enterKeyDown);
    username.onValueChanged.AddListener(delegate { selectUsernameInput(); });
    username.onEndEdit.AddListener(delegate { endEditingUsernameInput(); });
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{

}

void selectUsernameInput()
{
    usernamedataload.gameObject.SetActive(true);
    usernamedataload.content.GetChild(0);
}

void endEditingUsernameInput()
{
    usernamedataload.gameObject.SetActive(false);
}

void enterKeyDown()
{

}
```